# How detect from which url a use comes

Tags: php

I have several blogs.
I also have a wordpress blog , which is the main one.

I am driving traffic from the blogspot to the main wordpress blog.
I want to display content or links based on from which url a user is coming from.

For example.

If a user is coming from www.anyname.com/mobile
I want to show mobile phone related conetnts.

If a user is coming from www.anydomian.com/laptops
I want to shows laptop related contents.

So - how to detect from which url a user is coming from ?
I have tried the "HTTP_REFERER" code , it shows only current url.

Comment: I would make dynamic webpages rather than hard coded urls. then you can use ?action=mobile and easily pull all mobile related content this way. Otherwise use pregmatch on the url to get everything after .com/

Comment: @Matt , But so far I am not even able to detect the link. Tried some HTTP_REFERER scripts , it shows no source url as result!!!

Comment: Have you tried SERVER commands like `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php/8891890#8891890 for more info on getting the url

Comment: @Matt , the script work when I send hits within the domain , but why its not detecting Goo.gl links ?

Comment: You could use a query string when linking between the sites? `another-domain.com?source=anydomian.com/laptops`... HTTP_REFERER would have been a good candidate if it wasn't for the fact that a lot of routers strips that header, as a privacy feature. Poorly configured redirects in between might lose that header, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/)

So if it is mobile you redirect them to any URL you want, if it's not then stay on the page